# Could not find method compile() for arguments project react-native-google-places

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, mobile-development

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/jhondev/Android/myapp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 158
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [project ':react-native-google-places'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

[image]